# PHP and cURL: Fetching a file returns a 403 error

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch a remote video file and save it through `cURL` and PHP. The file opens fine on the remote site. It opens with HTML5 player if I directly open the file URL in browser. This happens in incognito mode too.

But when I try to fetch it via `cURL`, the remote server returns

> 403 forbidden error

I checked the Firefox addon "Live HTTP Headers" and tracked each cookie the site is setting and I have tried sending those different cookies, user agents in HTTP headers. But no luck. I think it is not cookie issue because the file is opening directly in the browser in the incognito window. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: The file URL changes dynamically after a certain time.

Comment: what page? (padding)

Comment: I did'nt understand what you want to know ?